# How to add usernames to the NodeJS and socket.io Zoom Clone built by Clever Programmer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I was trying to build the Zoom Clone that the channel Clever Programmer built, and I wanted to display the usernames of the people in the call when they send chat messages. After prompting the user to enter their name and assigning the name to a variable, how to use it to display the username above their chat message? Please help.

For reference, this is their GitHub repository: https://github.com/CleverProgrammers/nodejs-zoom-clone